# Particle in a box in the momentum representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I'm self-studying a book about QFT. In one of the initial sections, the following statement appears:

> Solutions to the Schroedinger equation for a particle in a box of size $L$ are running waves $\psi(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt L} e^{\frac {ipx} \hbar}$.

(here L is the size of the box). This solution is with periodic boundary conditions $\psi(x)=\psi(x+L)$.

This confuses me since I remember that the solution for this problem is given by $\psi(x)=\sqrt {\frac 2 L} \sin \left(\frac {n\pi x} L\right)$.

Has this anything to do with the momentum representation of the wavefunction? I would appreciate if someone could provide some clarification on this.

Edit: as requested by those who commented, the book I'm using is "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur", at section 3.1

Comment: Probably your book (which one?) is using periodic boundary conditions (i.e. $\psi(L)=\psi(0)$).

Comment: Yes, the book uses $\psi(x)=\psi(x+L)$, which implies that the momentum p is quantized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both eigenfunctions of the particle in a box hamiltonian (for different boundary conditions). As such, superpositions of these can be used as basis functions to express more wavefunction solutions to their respective hamiltonians.

In both cases, the momentum is quantized. The non-periodic case has $k_n = \frac{n\pi}{L}$ where $n$ is an integer. In the later, case, the quantization requires solving a transcendental equation (will update answer with it).

For the $\sin$ expression, if we specify $n=1$, we will obtain the ground state solution to this Hamiltonian. We can specify some $p$ to obtain the ground state for the periodic potential. The ground state function will look like

$$\psi(x) = A_k e^{kx} + B_k e^{-kx}  $$
where $k$ is given by the solution to $e^{-kL} = \frac{ k-\lambda}{k+\lambda}$, for $\lambda > 0$ being the coefficient of the delta function at $x=0$.

Ultimately they are both sinusodial and are solutions to time independent schodinger equation the potential of some particle in a box potential (although I didn't manually check the one you provided because its a result quoted from a text).

The superposition solutions will look like these:

$$\sum_n \frac{c_n}{\sqrt{2L}} \sin{\frac{n\pi x}{L}}$$
and
$$\int dp \frac{\phi(p)}{\sqrt{L}} e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$$

The author was just specifying the eigenfunctions of the hamiltonian, and they are in fact different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right about the meaning of L (I edited the question to include this detail). The point I'm trying to understand is the following: am I right in assuming that both solutions I mentioned in my question (or the more complete ones you pointed out) are expressing the same entity (i.e. the wavefunction $\psi(x)$) only using a different vector basis?

Comment: Updated the answer for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the meaning of "box" (I know that sounds silly but please let me explain ;)): Your solution is the solution of Schrödinger's equation in an infinite potential well which forces the wave function to become $0$ outside that well. Your QFT-book, on the other hand, defines box (somewhat unintuitively) as periodic boundary conditions, i. e. $\psi(x+L) = \psi(x)$, so it's more of a box that mirrors its content to the outside world or something like that. That last condition is often used in QFT (though often not necessarily) because it makes you get rid of infrared divergence and have sums instead of integrals (which many prefer). Also, I think, it's a bit easier to define everything mathematically this way (but I'm not sure about that).